# VIsual studio: Run cleanup on completion of ordered test

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, ordered-test

Say I have an ordered test which contain test method A, B and C.

How can I Run cleanup on completion of the entire ordered test, not after each method completes but when the entire ordered test completes?

Answer (score 0):

In NUnit, use TestFixtureTearDown attribute which will run once per text fixture (Class)

In MSTest, use ClassCleanup attribute.

Comment: But my tests in a ordered test are from different classes and i want this cleanup to run only after all my tests gets completed in the ordered test

Comment: I'm assuming mstest since the concept of ordered test doesn't officially exist in NUnit. I would therefore suggest that you look into putting them all in their own assembly and using the assemblycleanup attribute. The other thing you might try is to create a test method that runs last and does the cleanup. That being said, writing test that are depend ant on each other like this is considered bad form. Each test should be able to run on its own. You really should consider restructuring your code so that each test is independent